# How to rename file after project is builded in gradle 5 kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Could you please help me to find a proper way to rename built artifact with Gradle 5 Kotlin DSL

I created a Gradle 5.5.1 Spring Boot 2 project based on Kotlin DSL.

After executing `gradle build` the built artifact is inside $buildDir/libs folder.

How can I rename it? Let's say I want to give a simple name - app.jar

````
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("idea")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}

group = "com.hbv"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

the<DependencyManagementExtension>().apply {
    imports {
        mavenBom(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.RELEASE"))

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    testImplementation("com.h2database", "h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security", "spring-security-test")

}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Configure [the `bootJar` task](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-jars) which is generating the jar and is a [gradle jar task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:destinationDir) and set its [`archiveFileName` property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveFileName):

```
tasks {
    bootJar {
        archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define `archiveBaseName` in `jar` task

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    archiveBaseName.set("app")
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = application.mainClass
        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = archiveVersion
        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = "Test for App"
    }
}
```